# why is the button not vertically aligned?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I made a simple demo in which I have a **div**  containing a button, but the button is not **vertically aligned** I used **line-height** as well as **position absolute** and **top** margin but it does not work. Why doesn't it work? Here is my code:

```
<div ng-app='app'>
<div ng-controller='first as f'>

   <div class='col-xs-4 text-center' style='background-color:red;height:70px;line-height:70px'>

     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" style:'position:absolute;top:10px'>Block level button</button>

   </div>

</div>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/naveennsit/pen/KVawpW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following css. Make button position absolute and div position relative.

```
.btn-block {
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 100%;
}

.col-xs-4 text-center{
  position:relative;
}
```

**[Working Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BjpyQK)**

**Note:** If possible try to avoid inline css.

Answer (score 0):

Try position:relative instead of position:absolute.

Answer (score 0):

You are using CSS incorrectly `style:'position:absolute;top:10px`.

it should be.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" style='position:absolute;top:10px'>Block level button</button>
```

or you can use this code this will also work fine.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" style='margin-top:10px;'>Block level button</button>
```

here is codepan which I've edited [click here](http://codepen.io/rhulkashyap/pen/yegyVz)